# Install ssl on Kubernetes digital ocean load balancer

Tags: docker, ssl, kubernetes

I am having a website running on container port 80 and 443. I am using ready docker image from docker hub.

I have enabled SSL on Kubernetes using ingress.

I can not generate a certificate inside the pod. If I create cert inside the pod manually then at the time of service Apache restart then the container will restart and the whole pod will be created again. The WHOLE setup will change as default in docker image.

So how to install SSL on this website. Currently, it is giving an error of self-signed certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is like you are describing, you are using a [self-signed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-signed_certificate) certificate.

If you want to remove the warning or error you will have to get a certificate from a well known [CA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority) like Comodo or Symantec. If not you will have to trust the CA that you used to create your self-signed certificate. [This is an example](https://superuser.com/questions/437330/how-do-you-add-a-certificate-authority-ca-to-ubuntu) on how to do it on Ubuntu.

Hope it helps!

Comment: ubuntu one not work. manually can't generate certificate inside pod.if container inside pod will restart whole pod recreate and config change.

Comment: any other solution ? current i think only i can do is tls on ingress.